# Adding Serial Ports to comboBox only if they are not in use! C#

Tags: c#, combobox, serial-port

I have some comboBoxes on different TabPages that show available serial ports. I can choose one port in a comboBox and connect to it to get Data. Now I want the comboBoxes to hide the ports that are already in use. Whats the best way to do that?

Here is what happens on a combobox dropdown:

```
    string[] portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    comboBox9.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var portName in portNames)
    {
        //checks if combox already contains same Item.
        if (!comboBox9.Items.Contains(portNames))
        {
            comboBox9.Items.Add(portName);
        }
    }




    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //<-- This block ensures that no exceptions happen
        if (_serialPort1 != null && _serialPort1.IsOpen)
            _serialPort1.Close();
        if (_serialPort1 != null)
           _serialPort1.Dispose();
        //<-- End of Block

        if (comboBox2.Text != "")
        {
            _serialPort1 = new SerialPort(comboBox2.Text, BaudRate, Parity.Even, 7, StopBits.Two);       //<-- Creates new SerialPort using the name selected in the combobox
            _serialPort1.DataReceived += SerialPortOnDataReceived;       //<-- this event happens everytime when new data is received by the ComPort

            _serialPort1.Open();     //<-- make the comport listen

            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: You are creating All items of combobox before the for loop. This will add all the ports to the combobox. `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` returns all the ports (both free ports and in-use ports) ?

Comment: Yes, it returns both, the free ones and these that are in use.

Comment: So how you decide which one is free and which one is in-use?

Comment: private SerialPort _serialPort1;

_serialPort.IsOpen

Comment: Ok..  This is what I understood. you have all the ports already populated in the combobox. Now when you call `SerialPort.GetPortName()` again you want to check which ports are in-use and you want to remove those ports from the combobox. Can you share the code where you are adding all the ports in combobox at first place? And what code you have written to remove the in-use ports from the combobox?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Removing the item from the combobox when you open the port is the obvious way to get ahead.  It is misleading however, you cannot discover that a port is in use by *another* application until you try to open it.  Only the exception you get tells you that it is in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change button_click event as following.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //<-- This block ensures that no exceptions happen
    if (_serialPort1 != null && _serialPort1.IsOpen)
        _serialPort1.Close();
    if (_serialPort1 != null)
       _serialPort1.Dispose();
    //<-- End of Block
    // Adding port back to the comboBox as it is not open now.
    comboBox.Items.Add(_serialPort1.PortName);

    if (comboBox2.Text != "")
    {
        _serialPort1 = new SerialPort(comboBox2.Text, BaudRate, Parity.Even, 7, StopBits.Two);       //<-- Creates new SerialPort using the name selected in the combobox
        _serialPort1.DataReceived += SerialPortOnDataReceived;       //<-- this event happens everytime when new data is received by the ComPort

        _serialPort1.Open();     //<-- make the comport listen

        //removing port from the comboBox as it is now open and in-use.
        comboBox2.Items.Remove(comboBox2.Text);
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = true;
 }
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me!
I had need this `comboBox.Items.Add(_serialPort1.PortName)`

Comment: But it only works if I remove the comboBox Dropdown event... So the serials ports shown in the comboBoxes are not current. How can I check if one port is open and that this port dont needs to be added to the comboBox? Or what do I need to change in the Drop Down event?
I already tryed: ` if (_serialPort2.PortName != portName & _serialPort3.PortName != portName & _serialPort4.PortName != portName & _serialPort5.PortName != portName & !comboBox9.Items.Contains(portName))
                    {
                    comboBox9.Items.Add(portName);
                    }`

Comment: Can you put your code in the question? Also share some more details about the code like when it gets executed, Form_Load, button_Click? It would be better if you can put some context around the code and business use case too. Sharing bit more of code which can explain the whole scenario would be helpful too.

Comment: Ok, I will do that!